Can Black Lotus alone enable the Turn 1 Channel-Fireball combo?
Reading about the rulings for Gilded Lotus, I've discovered that "add three mana of any one color" means: add three mana of a single color, not three mana of possibly distinct colors.
Black Lotus' text reads exactly the same. This means the widely known one-turn win consisting of Fireball, Channel and Black Lotus could not possibly work, since Black Lotus alone could not provide {R}{G}{G}.
Is this actually correct? Did the rule over this change?

You are correct that the exact combo of a Black Lotus, Channel, and Fireball is not enough to win the game. However, all you need to add to make it work is a land that produces red mana, a Mox Ruby, or a second Black Lotus.
The original text of Black Lotus, in Alpha, was

Adds 3 mana of any single color of your choice to your mana pool, then is discarded. Tapping this artifact can be played as an interrupt.

There's no reasonable way to interpret that as allowing a player to produce both green mana for Channel and red mana for Fireball.
Note that you also need that land just to have enough mana period, ignoring colors. If you start the Channel + Fireball combo with only 3 mana, you have to pay 20 life to have enough mana to deal 20 damage.

IIRC, an ancient rule stated that you may lose the game only at the end of your turn if your life is zero or less. So killing your opponent first would still count as a win. I also Read Somewhere(tm) that, in ancient times, before card limits existed, there were 20-fireball+20-channel+20-lotus decks precisely because of that combo.

That's a good point, I'm not fully sure about the old rules about losing the game from life loss. With that old deck you're referring to, you just need two black lotuses to make the combo work.

I always heard the combo as black lotus/mox ruby/channel/fireball, but a mountain could stand in for the mox.

I don't think the pre-6th edition rule that checked your life total only at end of phases/turns would have given you a win in that scenario; if both players were at 0 or less life the game would still be a draw. The rule allowed you to temporarily go to 0 as long as you were back to 1 or more life before the end of phase (by popping a Mirror Universe, for example).

@alecov The old rule was players would lose at the end of the current phase, not the end of your own turn. So even if that did work without the color issue, the game would end in the draw as both players would be at 0 life at the end of the phase

@ruds, I think the "mox ruby rather than mountain" came from the "no land mulligan" rule (used in Shandalar, and IIRC common at some times).  With no lands in the deck, you got two shots at getting the turn 1.

@Andrew I wish I had saved my 4th-ed rule booklets to check that rule again. Time flies :/

@alecov even if it had worked the way you said it does, you'd be the one to lose. Since Fireball is a sorcery, it would be your turn where you channel it off, without an extra source of mana, you'd both be at 0 at the end of your turn, and if you lose when you end your own turn at 0, that would mean your opponent wins the game.


This means the widely known one-turn win consisting of Fireball, Channel and Black Lotus could not possibly work, since Black Lotus alone could not provide {R}{G}{G}.
Is this actually correct?

Yes, but you can add plenty mountains to the deck.
Play mountain.
Tap mountain, R
Play lotus cost 0, (R left)
Use lotus (select green, GGG R)
Cast channel for GG  (R G left)
Channel 19 life to mana (1R 19 G)
Profit! I mean fireball R(x) with R and 20 as x.

Having a mountain in play means you are using more than black lotus "alone" to enable the combo. This is the point of the question, that you need an additional. mana source.
